# Is the Field Norm of a unit a unit?

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am currently studying various properties of norms and was curious if the following result is true, or if there is something close to it:
Given a Galois extension $K/F$ and an intermediate field $L$ with $[K:L]=p$ (where $p$ is prime), if $A\subset K$ is an order of $K$ and if $t\in A^{\times}$ (unit group of $A$), is
$$Nm_{K/L}(t)\in A^{\times} \cap L?$$

I was able to show $Nm_{K/L}(t)\in L$ since $[K:L]$ is prime, but I am not sure if
$$Nm_{K/L}(t)\in A^{\times}.$$

Comment: Did you mean to say that you showed $\operatorname{Nm}_{K/L}(t) \in A$? It's definitionally in $L$.

Comment: What do you mean by "definitionally?" My definition (product definition) does not imply that. Also, I do mean $A^{\times}$, but if you have a way to show it is in $A$ I am very interested.

Comment: Recall that $\operatorname{Nm}_{K/L}(t) = \prod_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K/L)} \sigma(t)$, and that $\sigma(t)$ is a unit for every $\sigma$ because $t$ is. Since the product of units is a unit, $\operatorname{Nm}_{K/L}(t)$ is a unit, and $\operatorname{Nm}_{K/L}(t) \in L$ by Galois invariance, so its inverse must also be in $L$. So it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Nm}_{K/L}(t) \in A^\times$.

Comment: Could you please explain how $\sigma(t)$ is a unit? For example, where does $\sigma(t)$ lie and does $\sigma(t^{-1})$ lie there as well? Also, when you say "suffices to show $Nm_{K/L}(t)\in A^{\times}$", I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: $\sigma(t)$ is a unit because the inverse of $\sigma(t)$ is $\sigma(t^{-1})$. Because $K/L$ is Galois and $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K/L)$, it follows that $\sigma$ sends anything in $K$ to something else in $K$, so $\sigma(t), \sigma(t^{-1})$ are both in $K$. To answer your question is equivalent to proving that $\operatorname{Nm}_{K/L}(t) \in A^\times$.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am not quite sure why $\sigma(t)$ is a unit (by unit I mean still lies in $A^{\times}$).

Comment: Oh I don't know why/whether $\sigma(t) \in A^\times$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for looking at it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out that this is not always true. I found a counter example with $K=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$, $\alpha=1+\sqrt{2}+i$, and $A=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. $A$ is indeed an order of $K$. If $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $Nm_{K/L}(\alpha)=4+2\sqrt{2}$ and it is not too hard to show that $4+2\sqrt{2}\notin A$.

Of course, it easy to show that if $K$ is a number field that is also a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and if $A=\mathcal{O}_K$, then for any intermediate field $L$, $Nm_{K/L}(\alpha)\in A$, $\forall \alpha\in A$.

Answer (score 2):

Given a finite extension $K/L$ and a subring $A \subset K, Frac(A)=K$, $B = A \cap L$,

For $a \in A$, let $R_1 = B[a]$, and pick iteratively some $a_{m+1} \in A$ such that $R_{m+1}= R_m[a_{m+1}]$ is a free $R_m$-module, until $R_M$ is of finite index in $A$. So $R_M$ is also a free $B$-module.

The field norm $N_{K/L}(a)$ is the determinant of the $B$-linear map $x \mapsto a x , R_M \to R_M$. So $N_{K/L}(a) \in B$.

If  $a \in A^\times$ then $1=N_{K/L}(aa^{-1})=N_{K/L}(a)N_{K/L}(a^{-1})$ and hence $N_{K/L}(a) \in B^\times$.

Comment: I am unfortunately not very familiar with modules (the idea makes sense, but I don't really understand most standard results). I am also note quite sure how the norm is the determinant of the map you proposed.

Comment: Because a $B$-basis of $R_M$ is also a $L$-basis of $K$. The point of $R_M$ is to make sense to the polynomial $N_{K/L}(a-t) \in B[t]$ and to think to integrality in term of finitely generated modules

Comment: I understand your argument now except for one detail. How do you know $R_1=B[a]$ is a free $B$-module? Also, if I understand correctly, your choice of $a$ does not matter, only that it lies in $A$.